# Cannot append big dataset of images to list?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am new to machine learning, as well as deep learning and python. I am working on a project about Face Recognition, using Fine tuning on Inception Resnet v2, and training it on CASIA-Webface dataset consists of 453 453 images over 10 575 identities. I have preprocessed this dataset, and each image has size of 299x299.

Firstly, I want to append all labels and images information into 2 lists named `labels[]` and `images[]`, then write them into 2 json files, and use them for training.

```
import cv2
import glob
import os
import random
from tqdm import tqdm
import progressbar
import numpy as np
from imutils import paths
from keras.applications import imagenet_utils
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

images = []
labels = []

image_path = list(paths.list_images('/home/Desktop/casia-299'))
random.shuffle(image_path)
labels = [p.split(os.path.sep)[-2] for p in tqdm(image_path)]
le = LabelEncoder()
labels = le.fit_transform(labels)


for imagePath in tqdm(image_path):
    img = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    images.append(img)

def default(obj):
    if type(obj).__module__ == np.__name__:
        if isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        else:
            return obj.item()
    raise TypeError('Unknown type:', type(obj))

import json

print("Write to Jason: ")
with open("/home/Desktop/jsons/X_train_triplet.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(images, f, default=default)
with open("/home/Desktop/jsonsy/y_train_triplet.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(labels, f, default=default)

print("Done preprocessing")
```

But due to the very big dataset, they cannot be loaded into `images[]` list completely. Using above code and run on my GPU, it only loaded 20% of all images, and then stopped, and lagging, and showed some MemoryError.

Then I decided to reduce some of my code to save more memory, like this:

```
for imagePath in tqdm(image_path):
    img = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    images.append(gray)
```

Converting all images into Gray scale (to reduce 3 channels of RGB) and it can loaded more images into my list, but still started to stop and lagging at ~70% of process.

I was so tired finding way to loaded all images for training but it seems to be impossible. I would be extremely appreciated if anyone could help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: It feels a bit strange to store the image data in a json file. I would recommend saving the filename perhaps as part of your array, then read the imaged data in when it's needed. From a quick calc, it would take over 40 GB of RAM to load all the images into memory at once.

Comment: Even I do not store data into json file, just load labels and images into labels[] and images[], it still run out of memory. I have not reached the "Write to json file: " part yet. I think the problem is about the append, not beacause of the json file.

Comment: This is not impossible of course, you just need to build a generator that only loads a batch of data at a time.

Comment: Please check out my new solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57487030/expected-input-5-to-have-4-dimensions-but-got-array-with-shape-24-1