# Expected input_5 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (24, 1)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

Due to my previous [preprocessing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57469382/cannot-append-big-dataset-of-images-to-list), I decided to have a new method to preprocessing dataset:

```
import os.path
import os
import tqdm
import glob
from imutils import paths
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

def getListOfFiles(dirName):
    listOfFile = os.listdir(dirName)
    listOfFile.sort()
    allFiles = list()
    for entry in listOfFile:
        fullPath = os.path.join(dirName, entry)
        if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
            allFiles = allFiles + getListOfFiles(fullPath)
        else:
            allFiles.append(fullPath)             
    return allFiles        

def main():  
    dirName = '/content/drive/My Drive/casia-299-small'
    save_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/face_recognition/inceptionv2'
    listOfFiles = getListOfFiles(dirName)
    completeName = os.path.join(save_path, "to_train"+".txt")
    completeName2 = os.path.join(save_path, "to_test"+".txt")

    file_to_write = open(completeName, "w")
    for file in listOfFiles: 
        string_name = file
        file_to_write.write(string_name)
        file_to_write.write('\n')
    file_to_write.close()


    file_to_write = open(completeName2, "w")
    for file in listOfFiles:
        label = file.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
        file_to_write.write(label)
        file_to_write.write('\n')
    file_to_write.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then I use to file `to_train.txt` and `to_test.txt` as two arrays in size of (number of images, 1), represent for paths to each image in dataset and labels of each image. I feed them to my CNN for training like this:

```
# Model 2 try (my)
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from imutils import paths
from keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2 import InceptionResNetV2
from keras.applications import imagenet_utils
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.layers.core import Dropout
from keras.layers.core import Flatten 
import numpy as np 
import random 
import os
from keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2 import InceptionResNetV2
import numpy as np 
import random 
import os
import cv2
import pickle 
from keras import backend as K 
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import *
from keras.optimizers import *
from keras import applications
import h5py


images = []
labels = []

image_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/face_recognition/inceptionv2/to_train.txt"
label_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/face_recognition/inceptionv2/to_test.txt"

with open(image_path) as fp:
    line = fp.readline()
    while line:
        line = fp.readline()
        my_string = line.replace("\n", "")
        images.append(my_string)

with open(label_path) as fp:
    line = fp.readline()
    while line:
        line = fp.readline()
        my_string = line.replace("\n", "")
        labels.append(my_string)

print("Images: ", images)
print("Labels: ", labels)


x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(images, labels, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)

print(np.shape(x_train), np.shape(x_test), np.shape(y_train), np.shape(y_test))

def convnet_model_():
    initial_inceptionv2_model = InceptionResNetV2(weights=None, include_top = False, input_shape = (299, 299, 3))
    x = initial_inceptionv2_model.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = Dense(4096, activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.6)(x)
    x = Dense(4096, activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.6)(x)
    x = Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis = 1))(x)
    convnet_model = Model(inputs=initial_inceptionv2_model.input, outputs = x)
    return convnet_model

def deep_rank_model():
    convnet_model = convnet_model_()

    first_input = Input(shape = (299, 299, 3))
    first_conv = Conv2D(96, kernel_size = (8, 8), strides = (16, 16), padding = 'same')(first_input)
    first_max = MaxPool2D(pool_size = (3, 3), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same')(first_conv)
    first_max = Flatten()(first_max)
    first_max = Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis =1))(first_max)

    second_input = Input(shape = (299, 299, 3))
    second_conv = Conv2D(96, kernel_size = (8, 8), strides = (32, 32), padding = 'same')(second_input)
    second_max = MaxPool2D(pool_size = (7, 7), strides = (4, 4), padding = 'same')(second_conv)
    second_max = Flatten()(second_max)
    second_max = Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis = 1))(second_max)

    merge_one = concatenate([first_max, second_max])
    merge_two = concatenate([merge_one, convnet_model.output])
    emb = Dense(4096)(merge_two)
    emb = Dense(128)(emb)
    l2_norm_final = Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis = 1))(emb)

    final_model = Model(inputs = [first_input, second_input, convnet_model.input], outputs = l2_norm_final)
    return final_model

deep_rank_model = deep_rank_model()
deep_rank_model.summary()

batch_size = 24
_EPSILON = K.epsilon()
def _loss_tensor(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, _EPSILON, 1.0 - _EPSILON)
    loss = 0.
    g = 1. 
    for i in range(0, batch_size, 3):
        try:
            q_embedding = y_pred[i]
            p_embedding = y_pred[i+1]
            n_embedding = y_pred[i+2]
            D_q_p = K.sqrt(K.sum((q_embedding - p_embedding)**2))
            D_q_n = K.sqrt(K.sum((q_embedding - n_embedding)**2))
            loss = loss + g + D_q_p - D_q_n

        except:
            continue

    loss = loss/batch_size*3
    return K.maximum(loss, 0)

print("Compile: ")
deep_rank_model.compile(loss=_loss_tensor, optimizer = SGD(lr = 0.001, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True))

def image_batch_generator(images, labels, batch_size):
    labels = np.array(labels)
    while True:
        batch_paths = np.random.choice(a = len(images), size = batch_size//3)
        input_1 = []

        for i in batch_paths:
            pos = np.where(labels == labels[i])[0]
            neg = np.where(labels != labels[i])[0]

            j = np.random.choice(pos)
            while j == i:
                j = np.random.choice(pos)

            k = np.random.choice(neg)
            while(k == i):
                k = np.random.choice(neg)

            input_1.append(cv2.imread(images[i]))
            input_1.append(cv2.imread(images[j]))
            input_1.append(cv2.imread(images[k]))

        input_1 = np.array(input_1)
        input = [input_1, input_1, input_1]
        print("Input shape: ": , np.shape(input))
        yield (input, np.zeros((batch_size, )))

from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

filePath = '/content/drive/My Drive/casia-299-small/model_2_try_2.h5'
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filePath, monitor = 'loss', verbose = 1, save_weights_only=False, save_best_only=True, mode = 'min')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

deep_rank_model.fit_generator(generator=image_batch_generator(x_train, y_train, batch_size), 
                              steps_per_epoch = len(x_train)//batch_size, 
                              epochs = 20, 
                              verbose = 1, 
                              callbacks = callbacks_list)
```

Then during the training process, I faced with this new problem:
`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_5 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (24, 1)`

Is there something wrong with my code? I'm really not sure. Anybody with help is a big appreciation.

Update:
During the training process, I have just noticed that not all output get the error: i used `print("Shape of input: ", np.shape(input))` in function `image_batch_generator`

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njf2G.png)

So I guess there's something wrorng with `cv2.imread()`, which is not always read images successfully. I wonder if anyone has caught this problem yet? I'm so confused right now?

Answer (score 0):

Conv2D which is used in your script requires an input shape with four dimensions, which means that you need to use `numpy.reshape()` to change the array with dimensions (24,1) into something like (1,24,1,3) (3 meaning RGB images). Here's the link to the documentation for numpy.reshape().

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: I dont understand, because my image_batch_generator() returns 4-dimensions.

Comment: I see, you need to place the Flatten() AFTER the Lambda, otherwise it flattens to two dimensions before the lambda